# Declare CSS3 transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 2732, 0) using jQuery .css();

Tags: jquery, css, animation

In my current project I am doing CSS3 animations using a library. In this case one of my element is getting

**CSS**

```
#element {
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 2732, 0)
}
```

CSS property in element style. Now I want to modify this `element.style` using jQuery as follows.

**jQuery**

```
$("#element").css("transform", "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 100, 0)");
```

but the above jQuery code is not working for me. Can any one help me how to do it using jQuery.

**EDIT**

> I am trying to reset matrix to matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 100, 0), so ideally my element should shift to extreme left side of the screen and then further animation should start from left to right. but now its not shifting towards left side. and starts moving from the right side to outside to the right window wall.

Comment: How it's not working?

Comment: Working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/gr7y85yc/1/

Comment: @Joel Almeida: it is working in your fiddle but in my project further animation starts from 2732 and not from 100. unfortunately I can not show you how my animation is working.. sorry.

Comment: @NileshMahajan in your example jQuery animation starts on 100.. change it to 2723 ? http://jsfiddle.net/gr7y85yc/2/

Comment: @NileshMahajan Please explain what do you mean by  `not working for me`

Comment: @Tushar : I am trying to reset matrix to matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 100, 0), so ideally my element should shift to extreme left side of the screen and then further animation should start from left to right. but now its not shifting towards left side. and starts moving from the right side to outside to the right window wall.